# download the site.xml from an eclipse update site

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know how I can download an eclipse update-site's xml file?

I tried to simply paste the website in a browser URL with no luck.

e.g. http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Install a plugin?

Comment: The file can be found at http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/site.xml, but I doubt this is what you want. It doesnt provide anything useful

Comment: Update sites based on a p2 repository don't always have a xml file. What are you trying to do?